# Como receber o valor do <select> no PHP ao selecionar uma opção

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como faço, para que quando o usuário selecionar uma opção, a variável do PHP `$idCourse` receba o `value` da opção selecionada.

Fiz esse código apenas para mostrar a ideia:

> Código

```
    <select name="valor" id="idCourse">
        <option value="1">Curso 1</option>
    </select>

    <?php 
       $idCourse = $_POST['valor'];
       $result = $pdo->selectAll($idCourse);
    ?>
```

Comment: tem que enviar usando um formulário ou usando jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu não sei se você precisa realmente fazer isso com javascript puro. Mas com jQuery e tudo bem mais fácil. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

**Javascript / jQuery e HTML:**

```js
$('#idCourse').on('change', function() {

   alert(this.value);

  $.ajax({
     url: "caminho/nome_arquivo.php",
     method: "POST",
     data: { valor : this.value },
     dataType: "JSON"  
  }).done(function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  }).fail(function(err) {
     console.log(err);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="valor" id="idCourse">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Curso 1</option>
</select>
```

**Código PHP:**

```
<?php 
    $idCourse = $_POST['valor'];
    echo $idCourse;
    ...
?>
```

Comment: Resolvido (eu acho). Obrigadão. :)